# Is it possible to complete The Interbank Incident with all seven starting characters?

Tags: the-interbank-incident

*[The Interbank Incident](http://www.lcurtisboyle.com/nitros9/theinterbankincident.html)* was an early adventure game for the Tandy Color Computer. Among its various innovations, you could select from seven different characters with different listed strengths and weaknesses, which may or may not impact gameplay (for example, one character was described as strong enough to kick down certain doors, another was well-dressed enough to get into certain establishments without a ticket, and a third was military, and could enter the base without hassle).

[image: The seven characters of The Interbank Incident] [image: Example of character entry]

The choice of character apparently also shuffled the locations of the items. [This FAQ](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/coco/616315-the-interbank-incident/faqs/62501) notes that the manual claims any character can complete the game, but they've only found solutions for three of the characters (and the walkthrough notes that some items are randomized, and I remember some other items also consistently did not show up in your inventory or in certain locations, based on the character picked, further complicating a single solution).

So, does anyone have proof that it's possible to complete the game with all seven characters? Or, alternately, proof that it is not possible?

Answer (score 4):

This should be possible, because the winning conditions and locations can change when a new game is started. Playing with a character in a new game may have a totally different solution / hideout location, and conditions for winning than the last time you played that character.

When the game is running, it keeps track of the character's attributes, such as which character it is, the money they have, and the particular solution for the game. I'll show an example with a screenshot (Bytes.jpg).

[image: Running the game in MAME]

I've highlighted with a small red rectangle and blue rectangle in the upper left, which are the actual bytes of the game in hexadecimal. The blue one corresponds to the character you're playing, and the red corresponds to the solution for that particular game (hideout location). For example, the 06 in the blue square corresponds to Allen. 00 would be for Karl, 01 would be for Bob, 02=John, 03=Jackie, 04=Alex, 05=Mick. The 0A in the red square is the solution, which for that particular game happened to be in Seattle.

The important point though, is that this value in the red square seems to be selected randomly when you start a new game with the same character. I had a game with Allen where I won in Rio (the byte vaue was 02) and the following game I won with Allen in Seattle, with that value in the screen shot 0A. (It wasn't at the submarine though, that just happened to be where I took the screenshot).

Fun fact - the other rectangles I drew on the screenshot, green and purple correspond to your money, on hand and in the bank respectively. You only see the bank balance in the screenshot since its covered, but compare $6552 to the hexadecimal number in the purple box. 1998 in hexadecimal is 6552. This byte value can be changed in MAME ;-)

When I ran it in MAME64 machine, it was located around memory location 084C - 08FC (you see that in the screenshot), but this may be different on other machines or architectures.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I'm not certain if that proves that there are solutions for the other characters.(although it is heartening to hear that Alan can be used).

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. If I can clarify, what I meant is that the solutions are randomized for the character when the game starts. So if Alan wins in Seattle, then for another game you play with a different character, it may have the same winning conditions. Any character could win in Seattle (for example), if that is the game they start with.

Comment: {nods} Some aspects of the characters apparently affect whether a given route works in the game, and so far, routes are only known for a few. Unfortunately, it does still seem unproven whether the game is (intentionally or unintentionally) made so that some characters don't have a viable path on a given playthrough. You still get my upvote, but I can't accept it just yet.

Answer (score 2):

I have won the game with all 7 characters. As already mentioned, the hideout is random, but each character has strengths and weaknesses. Also, some of the items are placed at random AND all the items are useful. If you get a clue that "... is a womanizer...", you need to wear a wig to get into the hideout. Sometimes you can kick open doors to gain access or use the rod on the tracker to open the manhole cover in Germany. The gold card can either open the secret hideout at the ATM or used to open a locked door.

There is ONE major bug, NEVER give the wallet to anyone. It will freeze the game.